# Expect a nested property in a templated function parameter that depends on the template type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want the "options" property of the parameter object to at least contain the "label" property.

I tried doing it on my own, but it won't compile.

```
interface BaseOptionType {
  label: string;
}

interface CreatableAutoCompleteProps<OptionType extends BaseOptionType> {
  name?: string;
  options: OptionType;
}

const CreatableAutoComplete = <_OptionType,>({
  name,
  options,
}: CreatableAutoCompleteProps<_OptionType>): number => {
  return 0;
};

export default CreatableAutoComplete;
```

I receive the following error.

`(type parameter) _OptionType in <_OptionType>({ name, options, }: CreatableAutoCompleteProps<_OptionType>): number`

`Type '_OptionType' does not satisfy the constraint 'BaseOptionType'.ts(2344)`

So, what would be the correct way to do this.

Comment: Can you post the text of the error message? Or better yet, reproduce the issue on the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and then share the link in your post.

Comment: @CRice sure, added it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Type '_OptionType' does not satisfy the constraint 'BaseOptionType'

Well, I think you just need to make `_OptionType` extend `BaseOptionType`.

```
const CreatableAutoComplete = <_OptionType extends BaseOptionType,>({
  name,
  options,
}: CreatableAutoCompleteProps<_OptionType>): number => {
  return 0;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QPIAczAD2IAKgJ64oDeAsAFDLIA2cARhEwFzIZhSgBzANz0AvvXqhIsRCgDCUCHDBsmEAIIBXMITmEAtrjWQAClEK4MAHjwFi5SsggAPSCAAmGNJhz4ipCggAPmRaBmQQOH0IAH5uXn4QYXpGCzsQDG5bfwcIETpxOnoEYl5kBSUVVjUtHT1DYxQAXmQrAH1s+0CnVwgPL3QsToDKABoggAowxkjo0ZTkNP8MeYLuCuVVDW1dAyMIU3NLduHcoIBKbhBNfXYoZCaQ6eRFME0oEGQABnzRfPoXLhCFAwMh3BB4JomKCNlUajt6vtIP86CUMqDFBgoaCWrCtrVdg0DhAphEohBuAByGCEQiU0aLPylbhUZhsDhU1hwKCU5CiUTnegAeiFjEYAD0YkA)

Comment: Ok, I get it. My mind was a bit stuck in the C++ way of templating, was thinking the compiler will instantiate the type, then check it. Thank you for helping me out.